# Can Linux Mint install without a new partition like Ubuntu can?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-mint

I'm on a Windows 7 box right now, and I was able to install Ubuntu 11 using Daemon Tools. This worked without creating a separate partition for Ubuntu, it's quite nice.

Is Linux Mint capable of the same type of installation?

Comment: Linux Mint is Ubuntu ;-)

Comment: @Aki Can you clarify a bit? I don't know much about Mint.

Comment: http://www.contrapositivediary.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  [Linux Mint contains their own version of Ubuntu's Wubi installer called *Mint4Win*.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Mint#Installation)

You should be able to install it the same way you do so with Ubuntu.